# VBA Index Match with Multiple Criteria and different sheets, rows and columns

Tags: excel, vba, criteria, index-match

I am currently working on matching three criteria from two different sheets, including matching data from a column to data from a row. This is the ("Master") reference sheet where I need to get the data and populate to the other sheet ("Monitor")

I have the working index match formula but the table is too big and it takes too long to run all the formulas in each cell. So I'm looking to have it in vba.

MASTER

[image]

I need to:

-match the customer name from "Monitor" with the Customer from the "Master"

-match the expected delivery date (from "Master") to the expected delivery dates in "Monitor" (upper left)

-and match the Mesh from the "Master" to the headers in "Monitor"

- which will then populate the table in "Monitor", capture and sum up all the "Qty ordered" if all criteria are met

MONITOR

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I usually just insert a helper column into which I concatenate all the columns I want to match on, then use that to do the Match. The concat usually runs very quickly as does the Match

Comment: If you are tagging `vba`, you will need to provide the code you are working with/trying, clearly stating the issues you are having, and if an error occurs, indicate wherein the code the error occurred.

Comment: Regarding your current `index`/`match` formula, please provide... if this comes down to having a column referenced versus a fixed range, that could be significantly impactful.